# C#, Como puedo obtener 2 números aleatorios que sumados y divididos entre 2 me de el promedio que ingresé al inicio en nota final

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de hacer un pequeño programa para poder ingresar un número, por ejemplo 70 y el número que se dividirá por ejemplo 2 y el software me da 2 números aleatorios que sumados y divididos por 2 me dan el promedio de 70. Por ejemplo en la imagen a continuación puede ver dónde: 1) es la nota final obtenida por un estudiante (la presento), 2) es el número de variables por las que la dividiré, por ejemplo (Prueba final y participación), así que finalmente dónde dice la Nota 1 y la Nota 2, el software necesita darme dos números aleatorios que se suman y dividir por 2, me da el promedio final y debe ser igual al número que ingresé, espero haberlo explicado bien. ¡Gracias de antemano !, esto me está volviendo loco.

pd: mi código está generando dos números al azar, puedes verlos en la imagen (54 y 76)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Muchas gracias @Edwardo Reyes, mas arriba adjunte la imagen de la interfáz , aquí pongo mi código tratando de solucionarlo.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int notafinal = int.Parse(txtnotafinal.Text);
            int nota1 = int.Parse(txtnota1.Text);






if (cmbmuestras.Text == "2") {
                dgvresultado.Columns.Add("", "Nota Final");
                dgvresultado.Columns.Add("","Nota 1");
                dgvresultado.Columns.Add("", "Nota 2");
                dgvresultado.Columns.Add("", "Promedio");
                dgvresultado.Rows.Add(txtnotafinal.Text, "","", txtnotafinal.Text);

                //Prueba Random Number  

                //int aleatorio1 = notafinal - 10;
                //int aleatorio2 = notafinal + 8;

                Random r1 = new Random();
                int number = r1.Next(50, 80);
                txtrandom1.Text = number.ToString();
                int number2 = r1.Next(50, 80);
                txtrandom2.Text = number2.ToString();

                int primer = int.Parse(txtrandom1.Text);
                int segundo = int.Parse(txtrandom2.Text);

                int resultado = primer + segundo;

                txtrandom3.Text = resultado.ToString();
```

}

Comment: Estás en SO en Español, traduce tu pregunta o terminará cerrada.

Comment: Gracias, no me había fijado, soy nuevo!

Comment: Tu pregunta encierra un error de concepto que nada tiene que ver con programación; si no con matemática pura y elemental, pues si los números a colocar tienen que dar como promedio un número predeterminado, tal ves el primer número pudiera ser generado de manera aleatoria, pero el segundo tendría que ser, calculado por medio de una expresión matemática adecuada.  Por otra parte, te señalo que es una practica asumida como principio en este sitio, que en tus preguntas aportes el código, de tus intentos por solucionar al problema.

Comment: A tu pregunta le faltó el código que escribiste intentando solucionar el problema;  no debes colocar el código como respuesta; pues lo que colocaste, no es en verdad una repuesta a tú problema; pues a pesar de que mis conocimientos en matemática son muy modestos, puedo afirmar que no puedes garantizar que el promedio de dos números aleatorios sea un valor predeterminado, si dos números son aleatorios, el resultado de cualquier operación matemática con ellos, sea promedio o cualquier otra, será también un numero aleatorio. Te recomiendo eliminar tu respuesta, editar la pregunta y colocarlo alli

Answer (score 2):

comparto con lo mencionado por Eduardo Reyez, es más un tema conceptual.

Lo que debes que entender es que no pueden ser los dos números *random*. Uno sí lo será y el otro será calculado en base al primero.

Partiendo de la base matemática, la formula quedaría así: 
(num1+num2)/2=70 
num1+num2=70*2 
num1+num2=140

Entonces, **num1** será el valor random y luego calculas **num2**, quedaría **num2=140-num1**

```
Random r1 = new Random();
int num1 = r1.Next(140);
int num2 = 140-num1;
```

Espero que te sirva!

Comment: Muchas gracias cpistine!, voy a probar desde que llegue a la casa, en sí pensaba que era possible hacer algo como que genere numeros random y mientras no sean igual al numero dado primeramente (ej 70) siga generando numeros, pero si logro hacerlo con tu consejo de un solo numero random estaría perfecto! , muchas gracias

Comment: @JoséLuisRodríguez pero vos necesitas dos números aleatorios que sumados den 70? O que promediados den 70?

La solución que te brindé es para armar dos números que promediados den 70.

Comment: sí así es, promediados!,

Comment: Genial entonces! Espero que te sirva, saludos!